# Rscript could not find function

Tags: r, rscript

I need to run several scripts via the bash shell using `Rscript` and some functions I use require the function `isGeneric`. However, in this case the process end like that (for example):

```
Error in .getLogLik() : could not 
find function "isGeneric"
Calls: main -> dredge -> .getLik -> .getLogLik
Execution halted
```

This can be reproduced as follows

```
# in the bash shell
echo "isGeneric('apply')" > /tmp/test.R
Rscript /tmp/test.R
```

Result:

```
Error: could not find function "isGeneric"
Execution halted
```

However, if we open a R session and type the following, it works:

```
# in the R shell
isGeneric('apply')
[1] FALSE
```

Would you know where the problem comes from and how to fix it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to `help(Rscript)`, `Rscript` doesn't load the methods package by default, because it's time-consuming. So you either need to specify it on the command line:

```
Rscript --default-packages=methods file.R
```

Or `library(methods)` at the top of the file you're calling.

Comment: Thanks Joshua it works just fine now. And sorry I didn't see the link between `isGeneric` and the `methods` package.

Comment: @LudoDuvaux: no worries. It's not an obvious link unless you've encountered this issue before.

Comment: I just ran into this with `Error: could not find function "is"`. The connection there is even less obvious!

Comment: the command (according to help(Rscript)) should really be:  `Rscript --default-packages=methods,datasets,utils,grDevices,graphics,stats` in order to have the same default packages as R -- if you just include methods, a bunch of other stuff is then missing